# Angular 7 - change detection doesn't work with ngx-build-plus custom webpack configuration

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) to customize build process for my Angular 7 app.
I have added **webpack.partial.js** file with following code:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    jsonpFunction: 'header'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'es6-promise'
    })
  ]
}
```

To run the app, I am using following command:

```
ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.extra.js -o
```

And here is my **angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "header": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/header",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",  
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",  
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "en": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.en.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "en",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
            },
            "fr": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.fr.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "fr",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "header:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "header:build:production"
            },
            "en": {
              "browserTarget": "header:build:en"
            },
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "header:build:fr"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "header:build"
          }
        },

      }
    },

  },
  "defaultProject": "header",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

The app works absolutely fine, if I run the app without custom config as follows:

```
ng serve
```

BUT, when I run app with custom webpack config, **change detection** does not work properly. A variable updated in component class does not get updated in template/view.

Whats wrong in using **webpack.partial.js**

Answer (score -1):

In order to use a custom webpack config, we’ll need the @angular-builders/custom-webpack dependency. Add it to your project as a devDependency like so:

```
$ npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack -D
```

We can then install moment to our project and import this into our project:

```
$ npm i moment --save
```

We can then create a custom webpack configuration that rips out any locales that we don’t specifically choose to keep.

Inside of the root of your project, create a new file named custom-webpack.config.js with the following:

```
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 plugins: [
  new MomentLocalesPlugin({
   localesToKeep: ['fr']
  })
 ]
};
```

This requires us to install the moment-locales-webpack-plugin:

```
$ npm i moment-locales-webpack-plugin -D
```

Afterwards, we need to configure angular.json to use this new configuration. Inside of the architect/build object, update the builder from @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser to @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser and add the customWebpackConfig key:

```
"architect": {
 "build": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
  "options": {
   "customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js",
    "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This is all we need to do if we only want our final, built, application to use the webpack config. However, if we wanted to test this config while using ng serve, we have one more thing to do.

Install the @angular-builders/dev-server custom web server from within npm:

```
$ npm i @angular-builders/dev-server -D
```

We can then update this inside of serve/builder in the angular.json file:

```
"serve": {
 "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server"
}
```

Comment: **ngx-build-plus** is an alternative to *@angular-builders/custom-webpack* to implement custom webpack configuration. My current setup works fine in dealing with i18n.